# ARRAY FILTERS in mongooDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec0471dfec11a07d80c9d07"),
        "name" : "jasper",
        "post" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec0473ffec11a07d80c9d08"),
                        "content" : "It,s all about........",
                        "title" : "THE NEEDY"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5ec0475afec11a07d80c9d09"),
                        "content" : "I know..........",
                        "title" : "The world"
                }
        ],
        "__v" : 2
}
```

I want to update the content part in a particular post. I am using mongoose.
I tried the below query.Though it isn't showing any error it isn't updating in the data in the database.

```
var id="5ec0471dfec11a07d80c9d07";
 var subid="5ec0473ffec11a07d80c9d08";
data.updateOne(
    {'_id.post._id':subid},
    {
      $set:{
        "$[post].post.$[rely].content":'ohkkk'
      }
    },
    {arrayFilters:[{"post._id":id},{"rely._id":subid}],new:true}
  );
```

Can you please help me find the error?

Comment: There is a document that matches `{'_id.post._id':subid}`, so there will be no upsert, but  there is no element in the `post` array matching `{"post._id":id}`, so nothing gets modified

Comment: Have you tried the solution I provided? Do you still need help with your question?

Comment: I tried but still it's not updating the data. The output in Mongoshell is{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 0, "modifiedCount" : 0 } while the output for the post(i.e.res.send('post')) is {"ok":0,"n":0,"nModified":0} in express app.@JakubASuplicki

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use `arrayFilters`, please try the code below:

```
data.updateOne({_id: id},
        { 
            "$set": {[`post.$[inner].content`]: 'ohkkk'} 
        },
        { 
            "arrayFilters": [{ "inner._id": subid }],
            new: true
        },
        function(err, post) {
            if (!err) {
                res.send(post)
            }
        })
```

Alternatively, since it is 1 level nested array you could do:

```
data.updateOne({ _id: id, "post._id": subid }, { $set: { "post.$.content": 'ohkkk' }, { new: true } })
```

Hope it helps.